# Need help identifying

Tags: identify-this-bike

[image]

I found this under my house a few years ago and I’m hoping someone could help identify it

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for the better photo.  I can see a reaction arm on the left chainstay by the rear axle, suggesting this has either a coaster rear brake or some kind of hand operated drum brake.

We can also clearly read ***LEADER SPECIAL*** written on the downtube.

This seems to be a New Zealand brand, also sold in Australia.   Bill Pratney was a successful cash rider on Leader bikes.  Manufacturer was Clark Cycles in Auckland, New Zealand.

More info:
https://theflyingwheel.blogspot.com/search/label/Leader%2FClarkes%20Cycles

[image]
 From https://www.classicrendezvous.com/New_Zealand/Clarkes.html   This dates to between 1925 and 1955 and mentions Leader as a brand.

Leader still exists as a brand, but its been sold off repeatedly and has no connection with the original Australian company.   https://www.leaderbikesusa.com/

Comment: That’s amazing, thank you !